# Dealing with REDCap multiple choice checkboxes

Tags: r, dplyr, redcap

So, when I export my REDCap data to R Studio, the multiple choice checkbox answers become their own variables instead of remaining one variable as it presents in REDCap. For example, the question about race allows the individual to select all races that apply to them, but in the data, race becomes 8 new variables to account for each checkbox option.

This is the only solution that I've found that works, but it's time consuming and requires a lot of quality checks. So, I'd love to find something more automatic that deals with this problem.

```
cleandata <- data %>% 
  mutate(race_cat = rowSums(data[,85:92]),    
        new_race = case_when(race_cat == 1 & race___5 == 1 & ethnicity != 1 ~ "White",
                             race_cat == 1 & race___2 == 1 & ethnicity != 1 ~ "Asian",
                             race_cat == 1 & race___3 == 1 & ethnicity != 1 ~ "Black",
                             race_cat == 1 & race___7 == 1 & ethnicity != 1 ~ "Other",
                             race_cat == 1 & race___1 == 1 & ethnicity != 1 ~ "AIAN",
                             race_cat == 1 & race___4 == 1 & ethnicity != 1 ~ "NHPI",
                             race_cat == 1 & race___8 == 1 & ethnicity != 1 ~ "Unknown",
                             race_cat == 1 & race___6 == 1 & ethnicity != 1 ~ "Multi-Racial",
                             race_cat == 0 & ethnicity != 1 ~ "Unknown",
                             ethnicity == 1 ~ "Hispanic",
                             race_cat > 1 ~ "Multi-Racial"))
  table(cleandata$new_race)
```

I've played around with the package REDCapR in the hopes that it would have something to solve this problem, but I haven't figured anything out yet.

Comment: Could you post a small sample of the dataframe? That would help people give advice. You could paste the result of `dput(head(data, 10))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a messy thing to try to generalize, because there's no guarantee that the `race` field will always be defined the way you have it defined. Specifically, what if the next project defines `race___1 = White` instead of `race___5`.

You can probably do a couple of things to make this transformation a little easier. From what you've written, the general flow of the logic is

1. Apply labels for subjects with exactly one selection
2. Apply multiracial label for subjects with more than one selection
3. apply unknown label for subjects with no selection
4. Apply Hispanic label for subjects with hispanic ethnicity

I might approach it in this manner:

```
categorize_race <- function(data,
                            output_name = "new_race",
                            race_map = list(White = "race___5"),
                            race_field = "race",
                            ethnicity_field = "ethnicity", 
                            ethnicity_hispanic = 1){
  # Identify fields with race categories
  regex <- sprintf("^%s___.+$", race_field)
  race_fields <- names(data)[grepl(regex, names(data))]
  
  # Get the sum of race categories for each record
  race_sum <- rowSums(data[race_fields])
  
  # Identify hispanic, multiracial, and unknown
  is_hispanic <- data[[ethnicity_field]] == ethnicity_hispanic
  is_multiracial <- race_sum > 1
  is_unknown <- race_sum == 0

  # Match the checkbox value to the label  
  RaceLabel <- data[race_fields]
  for (i in seq_along(race_map)){
    RaceLabel[[race_map[i]]] <- ifelse(RaceLabel[[race_map[i]]] == 1, 
                                       names(race_map)[i], 
                                       "")
  }
  
  # Collapse all of the labels into a single string
  # subjects with multiple labels will have a messy value, 
  # but that will eventually be overwritten to "Multi-Racial"
  new_race_value <- apply(RaceLabel, 1, paste0, collapse = "")
  new_race_value[is_hispanic] <- "Hispanic"
  new_race_value[is_multiracial] <- "Multi-Racial"
  new_race_value[is_unknown] <- "Unknown"
  
  data[[output_name]] <- new_race_value
  
  data
}

cleandata <- data %>% 
  categorize_race(race_map = list("White" = "race___5", 
                                  "Asian" = "race___2", 
                                  "Black" = "race___3", 
                                  "Other" = "race___7", 
                                  "AIAN" = "race___1", 
                                  "NHPI" = "race___4", 
                                  "Unknown" = "race___8", 
                                  "Multi-Racial" = "race___6"))
```

This function gives you full control over the mapping of the various options to their label, what field ethnicity is stored in, and what coded maps to hispanic.

I haven't tested it, so it may need some tweaking to get it working to your liking.